# python Dictionary substring key

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have a Dictionary like this

```
D={'Physician procedure note':a,'Dentistry Procedure note':b,'Podiatry Procedure note':c}
```

I want to search This dictionary with key "Procedure report" in the above dictionary. I want to find out near the closest key in the dictionary and extract value.

```
I have used this approach
search_key = 'Procedure report'
  

# Using items() + list comprehension 
# Substring Key match in dictionary 
result = [val for key, val in D.items() if search_key in key] 
  
# printing result  
print("Values for substring keys : " + str(result))
```

I am getting empty List. How can i change this.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: IF i  give "procedure report"  as a key to match . I want to retrieve al the keys 
 in above dictionary 'Physician procedure note','Dentistry Procedure note','Podiatry Procedure note'

Comment: what is the ```res``` dictionary? your ```D``` dictionary doesn't contain your search_key

Comment: Both are the same

Comment: none of the keys in the dict contains the text ```Procedure report```

Comment: OP is probably looking for string similarity

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
result = [val for key, val in D.items() if any([s.lower() in key.lower() for s in search_key.split(" ")])]
print(result)
```

Output

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by checking set intersection:

```
search_key = set('Procedure report'.lower().split(" "))

print([v for k, v in D.items() if search_key.intersection(set(k.lower().split(" ")))])
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to retrieve a list of values with corresponding keys match against search keys (partially), then `if search_key in key` won't work as that requires a full match.

One way you can do is

```py
# construct a set of search keywords
keywords = set(search_key.upper().split(" "))

D_filter = list(filter(lambda x: keywords.intersection(set(x[0].upper().split(" "))), D.items()))

result = [term[1] for term in D_filter]
```